# d3.js Tooltip do not receive data properly

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have d3 line chart with two lines full with events and made a html tooltip to show some data from these events on mousemove. Its working fine until the moment when you switch to show only one line, than the tooltip doesn`t receive any data. I`ve log the data and it is coming to the tooltip, but tooltip is not receiving it for some reason. Check the code bellow:

```
    const tooltip = d3.select('.Tooltip')
      .style('visibility', 'hidden')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')

function mousemove (event) {
      // recover coordinate we need
      const mouse = d3.pointer(event, this)
      const [xm, ym] = (mouse)
      const mouseWindows = d3.pointer(event, d3.select(this))
      const [xmw, ymw] = (mouseWindows)

      const i = d3.least(I, i => Math.hypot(xScale(X[i]) - xm, yScale(Y[i]) - ym)) // closest point
      path.style('stroke-width', ([z]) => Z[i] === z ? strokeWidthHovered : strokeWidth).filter(([z]) => Z[i] === z).raise()
      dot.attr('transform', `translate(${xScale(X[i])},${yScale(Y[i])})`)

      // console.log(O[i]) <-- this is the data for the current selected event and its fine after 
      changing the line shown

      tooltip
        .data([O[i]])
        .text(d => console.log(d)) <-- here i log what is coming from data and doesn`t return anything
        .style('left', `${tooltipX(xScale(X[i]), offSetX)}px `)
        .style('top', `${tipY}px`)
        .style('visibility', 'visible')
        .attr('class', css.tooltipEvent)
        .html(d => chartConfig.options.tooltip.pointFormat(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `tooltip.data([0[i]])`, d3 returns a selection of elements already associated with your data, which does not make sense for your tooltip. If you already computed the value you want to show (I assume it is *O[i]*), then simply set the text or the html of the tooltip:

```
tooltip.html(chartConfig.options.tooltip.pointFormat(O[i]);
```